# odoo 8, Issue with permissions over models

Tags: permissions, odoo

I am trying to read companies data with:

```
for company in self.pool('res.company').browse(cr, uid, uid):
    company.vat <=== code breaks here
```

If i use the administrator (uid 1) account i see company.vat. But if i use any other account (which have permissions to res.company) i get a message: "One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted..."

Is this a permission issue or a coding error of sorts? Mind that if I hard code 1 instead of uid as a parameter to browse function it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all if it is a case where you have only one company in your odoo,by default when you create,it will be created with the id as "1".
2. You are able to access that record with "Administrator" because,the id of the admin user is also "1". So this is resulting in browse(cr, uid, uid) replaced by (cr, 1, 1). As the uid = "1" for administrator and only company record's id is also "1".
   3.When you are logging in with some different user,the uid will not be "1". So in that case you cannot read that company with uid,as ('uid != 1','company_id = 1') does not match.In this case you may get an error like "One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted".
   4.So you do one thing,perform a search operation first which will yield you the company_ids and then repeat the for loop by reading the companies.

> ```
> company_pool = self.pool.get("res.company")
> company_ids = company_pool.search(cr, uid, [])
> for company in company_pool.browse(cr, uid, company_ids):
>     company.vat
> ```

Comment: Mr. Sharavan this worked! Still don't really understand why though. Marked as answer, and marked as useful dont know why doesnt it show as useful.

Comment: as in odoo, by default only one comany record will be present. So, its ID is 1. As when you are trying to login with admin [by default UID 1] its able to fetch that record as company record with ID 1 is present. When you are trying with other users [suppose uid 10] then there is no company record with ID 10. So, what i did is, passed an empty domain in search method, it will return all company_ids [i.e., at present [1] iff only one record is available]. Then browse the ids to access the required data.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID

self.pool('res.company').browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, uid)
```

Comment: Is this safe? It seems same kind of "hack" as me writing in 1. It will probably work but it smells fishy:)

Comment: def someFunction(self, cr, uid, order, selling_company_vat) { plus the code above, that's the code }